# ExpressJS: push query values in array and route to ejs

Tags: mysql, arrays, express, for-loop, ejs

I need to get query values which will be routed to ejs file. I am able to do that using `data:rows`. However, this gives `solution:Sandy`. I only need `Sandy`. Below, I am pushing the values i.e. `rows[i]` using for loop into array `arr`, however, only the last element stays in the array. I tried using `forEach` loop which is giving syntax error. Any ideas/help would be highly appreciated!

main.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var router = express.Router()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var arr = [];
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'host',
  port     : 'port',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});

connection.connect()
connection.query('SELECT customer_name as solution FROM customers', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err
    for(var i in rows){
        arr.push[rows[i].solution];
    }
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', {data:arr});
    });
})
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

index.ejs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title></title>

  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
<<h1><%= data %></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be executed when the users hit the `/` route, this way they will always receive updated data from the server, also there is no need to create another array, you can just pass the query result to ejs and then loop through it:

**main.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'host',
port     : 'port',
user     : 'user',
password : 'password',
database : 'database'
});

connection.connect();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    connection.query('SELECT customer_name as solution FROM customers', function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) throw err;

        res.render('index', { data: rows });

    });

});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title></title>

<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>

    <% for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>

        <h1><% data[i].solution %></h1>

    <% } %>

</body>

</html>
```